# cursor value has not been set with registeroutparameter while executing a postgres function in java using jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Here is my java code:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
        java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
                    import java.sql.CallableStatement;
        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.SQLException;
        import java.sql.Types;


public class postgresFn {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
         sampleFn();
     }
     static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/postgres";

   static final String USER = "user";
   static final String PASS = "password";
public static void sampleFn() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call function(?,?,?) }");
con.setAutoCommit(false);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
cstmt.setInt(1, 2);
cstmt.setInt(2, 4);
cstmt.execute();
rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);
 rs.close();
 cstmt.close();
 con.close();
}}
```

and the procedure is :

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_em(integer ,integer, refcursor) RETURNS refcursor AS 
            $BODY$
            DECLARE

    a ALIAS FOR $1;
    b ALIAS FOR $2;
    Result ALIAS FOR $3;
    BEGIN
    open Result for
        SELECT $1 + $2;
        RETURN Result;
        END;
    $BODY$
     LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am getting this error :

```
 ERROR: function test(integer, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

why I am getting this error.. mistake. since ref cursor is giving the result I used registeroutparameter to get the resultset .I think all syntax are correct. I don't know where i did

Comment: That's because you registered it as an out parameter.

Comment: @ Craig Ringer, Since I am new to postgresql I didn't get your point. kindly help me.

Comment: how to set value for out parameter from java

Comment: Folks, please don't downvote without explaining why! Especially when there's the code, a reasonable description, and the exact error provided.

Comment: No time to explain tonight, will try in the morning.  In the mean time see the examples in the manual: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/callproc.html . Let me know if you're still stuck. If you solve it yourself, please post an answer to your own question and tell me so I can upvote.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I also just referred this link only. I am also using this method to get result set. kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: You must use `{ ? = call myfunc(?, ?) }` per the documentation (http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/callproc.html#callproc-resultset-refcursor) . My answer was wrong as I hadn't noticed it was a refcursor and I have no time to test a follow-up.

Comment: Hi Craig Ringer, I have tried with this method.. same error only throwing..